# C++ Error on vector of objects containing threaded function

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, openframeworks

do you know of any method (C++) to create a vector of objects containing a threaded function? Ideally the technique has to be crossplatform (Win/OSX) and easily portable to mobile (iOS). It can be very basic multithreading, the function to be run in parallel is pretty simple (but computationally intensive).

I am writing an application  with many objects (belonging to the same class) having a quite complex data structure which needs to be analysed in parallel: while the main application thread takes care of interacting with the user and rendering the scene, each object gets its data analysed in parallel on separate threads.

*So far I tried to prototype the app in OpenFrameworks (using ofThread), but as soon as I start creating a vector of objects containing a threaded function the compiler throws some weird errors (see below for reference).*

*(OpenFrameworks example)*

```
class MyClass: public ofThread
{
     int A, B, C;
     void threadedFunction();
     MyClass();
}
```

*... if I instantiate the class (run its methods, including the threaded function) no problem.*

I then create a vector of this class:

```
// in main function
...
vector<MyClass> myList;
```

*...  but now as soon as I try to add an instance of the class to the vector, the compiler fails saying that it cant access privte members in class Poco:FastMutex (utils\ofthread.h(190): error C2248: 'Poco::FastMutex::FastMutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Poco::FastMutex' and Poco:Thread (utils\ofthread.h(190): error C2248: 'Poco::Thread::Thread' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Poco::Thread')*

```
// in main function
...
myList.push_back(MyClass());    //ERROR!
```

.

```
// in main function
...
MyClass temp;              //OK SO FAR
myList.push_back(temp);    //ERROR!
```

**Any help welcome!**

Comment: At a guess I'd say `FastMutex` isn't copyable (or moveable) which `std::vector` requires. You can probably get it to work by storing a smart pointer in the vector rather than the object itself.

Comment: Anything wrong with `std::vector<std::thread>`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a copy of a mutex. Your `push_back` function tries to create a new instance of `MyClass` in the vector as a copy of `temp`. You can use a vector of smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 1):

In openFrameworks, we have a `typedef` called `ofPtr` which attempts to wrap `std::shared_ptr<>`.  Avoid it as it will probably be disappearing soon.  Instead I recommend using `std::shared_ptr<>`, which is available to all platforms that openFrameworks currently supports.  For example:

```
// Your .h header file
std::vector<shared_ptr<YourClass> > vectorOfYourClassInstances;

// Your .cpp/.mm implementation file

std::shared_ptr<YourClass> yourClassInstance = std::shared_ptr<YourClass>(new YourClass);

vectorOfYourClassInstances.push_back(yourClassInstance);

// The place where you are using your class
// Iterate through using an index or an iterator
// std::vector<shared_ptr<YourClass> >::iterator ...

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < vectorOfYourClassInstances.size(); ++i)
{
    std::shared_ptr<YourClass> onOfYourClassInstances = vectorOfYourClassInstances[i];

    onOfYourClassInstances->makeItDoAThing(); // make it do a thing 
}
```

When you erase an object from your vector, the `std::shared_ptr`will keep track of the number of references and will call your class' destructor (`YourClass::~YourClass() { }`) automatically freeing the memory for you.

Currently openFrameworks does not fully support C++11 (it is under active development), but when the time comes, you can use C++11's `std::make_shared` function and potentially `std::unique_ptr` if that is more appropriate for your application.